# How to deal with nested list?

Tags: c, linked-list, nested, fill

H. I'm writting program to analyse code in pascal. I've created such lined-lists

```
typedef struct lista1   //list which contains var, const and types!
{
    int rodzaj; //1 - variables, 2 - constants, 3 - types
    char nazwa[128];
    char add[128];
    struct lista1 *wsk;
}lista1;

typedef struct lista2
{
    int rodzaj; //1 - procedures, 2 - functions
    char nazwa[128];
    char typ[128];
    struct lista2 *wsk;
    lista1 *var_loc;
    lista1 *const_loc;
    lista1 *type_loc;
}lista2;
```

my question is: how to fill those nested lists(var_loc, const_loc, type_loc)? I've tried to do some function in this purpose but I have lot of errors. Please, show me how to do it.

Comment: That looks like you want to make your `lista1` structs linked lists with `var_loc`and so on as heads. Plenty of code exists for that here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code creates an external list (head) with 5 elements, each of them with an internal list of 10 elements:

```
int i, j;

lista2 *head = NULL, *new=NULL;
lista1 *new2 = NULL;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    new = (lista2*)malloc(sizeof(lista2));
    new->wsk = head;
    head = new;
    new->var_loc = NULL;
    sprintf(new->typ, "external list, element %d", i);
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){
        new2 = (lista1*)malloc(sizeof(lista1));
        new2->wsk = new->var_loc;
        new->var_loc = new2;
        sprintf(new2->add, "internal list, element %d", j);
    }
}

// Print list contents
lista2 *p2;
lista1 *p1;

for(p2 = head; p2; p2=p2->wsk){ // iterate over ext. list
    printf("%s\n", p2->typ);
    for(p1 = p2->var_loc; p1; p1 = p1->wsk){ // iterate over int. list
        printf("  %s\n", p1->add);
    }
}
```